# Save logs to different spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, export

I'm currently using the below code which logs any searches made within columns 4,10,11,12 in the sheet called Postcode Checker to a sheet called 'APP_logs(Raw)'

Due to the size of the logs I've noticed that the main checker is becoming bogged down so I'm wondering if it's possible to have the script export the logs to a separate spreadsheet let's say named 'search_logs' so that they are completely separate to the main spreadsheet?

The script currently logs any postcodes entered into column 4 in cells D7:D18 top a sheet called APP_logs(RAW) and then any postcodes that are entered in to cells J8:L18 are logged in a sheet called PUB_logs(RAW). I've added a screenshot below of the main checker below.

[image: main checker]

Essentially it then logs the postcode entered into column B and a timestamp of when it was searched for in column A of either PUB_logs(RAW) or APP_logs(RAW) as appropriate. I've added a screenshot of this below.

[image: logger sheet RAW]

**Edit** To clarify, I want to know if it's possible for the script below to send the search logs to another spreadsheet entirely, the logs should not be entered or saved anywhere within the Postcode Checker spreadsheet. I read somewhere that instead of getActiveSpreadsheet() I could us:  open(file), openById(id) or openByUrl(url) and then instead of a simple trigger, use an installable trigger but I have no idea where to start with that.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (!e) {
    throw new Error(
      'Please do not run the onEdit(e) function in the script editor window. '
      + 'It runs automatically when you hand edit the spreadsheet.'
    );
  }
  logColumns_(e);
}
 
/**
* Automatically logs changes in columnsToWatch in sheetsToWatch.
*
* @param {Object} e The onEdit() event object.
*/
function logColumns_(e) {
  // version 1.2, written by --Hyde, 10 February 2022
  //  - see https://support.google.com/docs/thread/150138311
  // version 1.1, written by --Hyde, 30 July 2014
  //  - see https://productforums.google.com/d/topic/docs/7CaJ_nYfLnM/discussion
  // version 1.0, written by --Hyde, 10 August 2013
  //  - see https://productforums.google.com/d/topic/docs/az365_ypIV0
  if (!e.value) {
    return;
  }
 
  ////////////////////////////////
  // [START modifiable parameters]
const parameters = [
    {
      sheetsToWatch: /^(Postcode Checker)$/i,
      columnsToWatch: [4,10,11,12],
      changelogSheetName: 'APP_logs(RAW)'    
    },
  ];
  // [END modifiable parameters]
  ////////////////////////////////
 
  const sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  const sheetName = sheet.getName();
  const settings = parameters.filter(setting => sheetName.match(setting.sheetsToWatch))[0];
  if (!settings || !settings.columnsToWatch.includes(e.range.columnStart) || sheetName === settings.changelogSheetName) {
    return;
  }
  const columnLabel = sheet.getRange(sheet.getFrozenRows() || 1, e.range.columnStart).getValue();
  const rowLabel = sheet.getRange(e.range.rowStart, sheet.getFrozenColumns() || 1).getValue();
  let changelogSheet = e.source.getSheetByName(settings.changelogSheetName);
  if (!changelogSheet) {
    changelogSheet = e.source
      .insertSheet(settings.changelogSheetName, e.source.getNumSheets())
      .appendRow(['Timestamp', 'Sheet name', 'Cell address', 'Column label', 'Row label', 'Value entered']);
    changelogSheet.setFrozenRows(1);
  }
  
const pubSearchLogShet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("PUB_logs(RAW)");
  const col = e.range.getColumn();

  if (col == 4){
    changelogSheet.appendRow([new Date(), e.value])    
  }

  else if(col == 10 ||col == 11 ||col == 12 ||col == 13 ||col == 14){
    pubSearchLogShet.appendRow([new Date(), e.value])
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your goal is to just paste data from your logs from one spreadsheet to a different one.

If so, you can easily reference another spreadsheet that you have created by it's ID or URL using the openbyId() or openByUrl() methods for example, and then just use the setValue() or setValues() methods to paste the data.

See the following code as an example:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  if (!e) {
    throw new Error(
      'Please do not run the onEdit(e) function in the script editor window. '
      + 'It runs automatically when you hand edit the spreadsheet.'
    );
  }
  logColumns_(e);
}
 
/**
* Automatically logs changes in columnsToWatch in sheetsToWatch.
*
* @param {Object} e The onEdit() event object.
*/
function logColumns_(e) {
  // version 1.2, written by --Hyde, 10 February 2022
  //  - see https://support.google.com/docs/thread/150138311
  // version 1.1, written by --Hyde, 30 July 2014
  //  - see https://productforums.google.com/d/topic/docs/7CaJ_nYfLnM/discussion
  // version 1.0, written by --Hyde, 10 August 2013
  //  - see https://productforums.google.com/d/topic/docs/az365_ypIV0
  if (!e.value) {
    return;
  }
 
  ////////////////////////////////
  // [START modifiable parameters]
const parameters = [
    {
      sheetsToWatch: /^(Postcode Checker)$/i,
      columnsToWatch: [4,10,11,12],
      changelogSheetName: 'APP_logs(RAW)'    
    },
  ];
  // [END modifiable parameters]
  ////////////////////////////////
 
  const sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  const sheetName = sheet.getName();
  const settings = parameters.filter(setting => sheetName.match(setting.sheetsToWatch))[0];
  if (!settings || !settings.columnsToWatch.includes(e.range.columnStart) || sheetName === settings.changelogSheetName) {
    return;
  }
  const columnLabel = sheet.getRange(sheet.getFrozenRows() || 1, e.range.columnStart).getValue();
  const rowLabel = sheet.getRange(e.range.rowStart, sheet.getFrozenColumns() || 1).getValue();
  let changelogSheet = e.source.getSheetByName(settings.changelogSheetName);
  if (!changelogSheet) {
    changelogSheet = e.source
      .insertSheet(settings.changelogSheetName, e.source.getNumSheets())
      .appendRow(['Timestamp', 'Sheet name', 'Cell address', 'Column label', 'Row label', 'Value entered']);
    changelogSheet.setFrozenRows(1);
  }
  
  //const pubSearchLogShet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("PUB_logs(RAW)");
  // Edited line here:
  const pubSearchLogShet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("Introduce the URL of your file here").getSheetByName("Introduce the name of the sheet on that file where you want to have the logs");


  const col = e.range.getColumn();

  if (col == 4){
    changelogSheet.appendRow([new Date(), e.value])    
  }

  else if(col == 10 ||col == 11 ||col == 12 ||col == 13 ||col == 14){
    pubSearchLogShet.appendRow([new Date(), e.value])
  }
}
```

#### References:

- [openById(id)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyidid)
- [openByUrl(url)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyurlurl)

Comment: not quite, I have added some clarity to the main question. thanks

Comment: @James'Mook'Pite could you share some sample data that could be used to differentiate what information should remain on the sheet with the apps script and what are the logs that should be moved to a different sheet? I was trying to understand from the code which variables are making reference to the location where the code is writing data and I believe that `changelogSheet` and `pubSearchLogShet` are the ones that need to change but I'm not sure if one of them is considered something other than "the logs"

Comment: amended the main question with some screenshots and explanations for you. hope that helps.

Comment: @James'Mook'Pite If I understand correctly, the logs you are referring to that you want to change are only the ones from the 2nd screenshot you shared, correct?

Comment: yes just the postcode and date of search. if possible searches from column 4 will go to one sheet in the new spreadsheet and any from the other columns will go to another sheet. thanks

Comment: @James'Mook'Pite edited my answer. Let me know if that works. It's pretty much the same I explained before but applied to your code. If that does not work as expected, I think having a demo file would be better to try to use it to reproduce the exact same expected result there.